# issue with overflow:auto

Tags: css, overflow

On the following page, despite not really having anything that breaks the structure, themain content panel `(#textAreaCont)` drops below the **sidebar** - unlike any of the other pages in the site.

***[Site Link](http://bit.ly/SuKc4u)***

if i reduce the `width` of `#textAreaCont` to about `683px` - it helps, but then i still have that `scrollbar` - which is there because of the `"overflow: auto"` on the `#container`

any ideas on this?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Give to overflow:hidden of #container

Comment: why you just don't remove `overflow:auto` ?

Comment: removing the overflow competely means the footer misebhaves - so i need that. The overflow hidden seems positive though - checking it out.

Comment: Rohit's answer works - thanks. How can i mark it as such?

Comment: @Rohit Azad - can you post your comments as an answer - so that i can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Hi now used to  `overflow:hidden` of `#container`

as like this

```
#container{
overflow:hidden;
}
```